# Spring Integration (not Basic Spring) support for Drools

Tags: spring, spring-integration, drools

Do we have examples or out of box support to use Spring Integration(not Basic Spring) as opposed to Camel with Drools like in link [here](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#ch.camel)?

What I would looking for is a way to build/set-up [Decision Tables](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#drools.GuidedDecisionTableEditor)
and be able to use Spring Integration framework already existing in my application.

I have read about [Spring](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#ch.kie.spring) but what I am looking for is Integration Framework support - specifically [Spring-Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) as opposed to [Apache Camel](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#ch.camel)

Any pointers for basic set-up appreciated.

Comment: Please avoid referencing outdated documents and read the up-to-date documentation for Drools 6.1.0, which contains a section 11, Integration with Spring.

Comment: Updated the question - with links

Comment: Indeed, there is a Section 12, Apache Camel Integration, in the documentation for 6.1.0. But note that I was pointing at **Section 11, Integration with Spring**.

Comment: Agreed! But sorry I am not talking about Section 11 Spring but - Spring Integration framework (link above) which implements EIP like Apache Camel

Comment: Sorry here too, but at least we have clarified the issue.

Comment: I'd say that you should use that Drools-Camel fusion and route the result to the Spring Integration MessageChannel. camel.apache.org/springintegration.html. Spring Integration doesn't support directly Drools and there is no plans.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan : Appreciate the help from Spring Integration leads as usual :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think would be better if I move my comment to the answer to close this question:

I'd say that you should use that Drools-Camel fusion and route the result to the Spring Integration `MessageChannel` http://camel.apache.org/springintegration.html. Spring Integration doesn't support directly Drools and there is no plans.

The main reason - "do not reinvent the wheel".

Since Drools lives in JBOSS very well and has that Camel integration, there is no reason to find alternative solution.

Right, it's not a position of Spring Integration developer, but we just don't want to start a new holy war "Camel VS Spring Integration" :-).

Comment: Although not re-inventing the wheel is a good reason for SI, but what would be overhead of having one more integration framework in the application and how would I defend the choice of SI over camel?